# Does socket.io-client work on react native android?

Tags: react-native

Have anyone successfully used socket.io-client with react-native-android? I did some searching but it seems to be a mix bag.

I'm trying to figure out if I should use it for my project and I don't have the android version setup yet. So I want to see if it actually works before I jump the gun.

Answer (score 0):

I have https://github.com/gcrabtree/react-native-socketio successfully working on android with React-Native 0.39. There does however appear to be an issue with the socketConfig parameters not being parsed correctly when compiled but you can get around this by adding the parameters to the socket connect url (obviously not all paramaters can be passed into the connection url). My code for connecting to a room that has token authentication

```
    this.socket = new SocketIO(`${this.baseUrl}/${this.socketRoom}?token=${GlobalState.socketToken}`);
    this.socket.on('connect', () => resolve());
    this.socket.connect();
```

I am yet to get this working on iOS though.